# Как сделать кликабельным номер телефона или кнопку вызова

Tags: php

в интернете есть примеры, все под какой нибудь CMS,
у меня другой случай, код который выводит номер телефона -

```
echo '<span id="sendtel" ><a href="javascript:send_tel('.$rr['id'].')">Показать номер телефона</a></span><br>';
```

Как и куда вставить вторую ссылку или кнопку ?
Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Думаю вал лучше пробовать решить этот вопрос с помощью JS, создадите себе span#out и при клике на "показать телефон" присвойте этому span'у номер телефона

Comment: Здравствуйте, это что то из высшего пилотажа, где можно почитать примеры ?

Comment: Это вовсе не сверхмагия) Вскоре напишу свой вариант решения задачи)

Comment: Спасибо, очень жду.

Answer (score 4):

У вас нет необходимости использовать JS для решения подобных задачи, такие вещи работают на уровне HTML.

По правилам HTML номер телефона, емейл и прочие мета-данные необходимо помещать в тег ссылки:

```
<a href="#"> ссылка </a>
```

Чтобы разместить номер телефона, на который можно нажать и позвонить необходимо использовать аттрибут тега ссылки:

```
<a href="tel:+74952680449">+7 (495) 268-04-49</a>
```

Аналогично будет и с e-mail.

```
<a href="mailto:mymail@gmail.com">mymail@gmail.com</a>
```

Так же через тег ссылки можно открывать и любые другие приложения пользователя, к примеру Skype.

```
<a href="skype:Skype_User">Skype_User</a>
```

Если мой ответ Вам помог, то проголосуйте за него пожалуйста.

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо за ответ. Да это если один телефон или пять, о когда их тысячи и они выводятся с БД, как в таких случаях ?

Comment: Точно так же, но вместо номера телефона в моем примере выводить номер телефона из БД. Что у вас за CMS?

Comment: Самописная, тот код что в вопросе, выводит номер на странице объявления, потом javascript и еще страница с запросом в БД

Answer (score 1):

Я расскажу, как бы я это реализовал) Имем, к примеру, в БД 1000 фирм и у каждой свой телефон. Для начала определимся, что будет служить ключом для вывода какой то конкретной строки из БД, это может быть название фирмы или адрес, главное, что бы этот ключ был уникальным для каждой строки

Cоздаете в html

```
<input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Начните вводить название фирмы">
```

"слушаете" пользовательский ввод, например через addEventListener('input', searching) - в данном случае 'input' это будет метод, на который реагирует JS, а searching функция, которая и будет "икать". Давайте по порядку:

```
// Обращаемся к инпуту и начинаем слушать изменения
let input = document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('input', searching);
// Тут будет подгружен номер телефона
let out = document.getElementById('out');
```

в теле JS запроса создаем простейший запрос, не требующий обновлений страницы:

```
        // та самая функция searching
        function searching()
        {
            let inputed_data = document.getElementById('input').value;
            out.style.display = 'block';

            fetch('php/handlers/helper.php?input='+inputed_data)
            .then(data => {
                return data.text()
            })
            .then(data => {
                out.innerHTML = data;
            })          
        }
```

Ну а теперь непосредственно обработчик, он тоже очень простенький:

```
<?php

// Перемешка, которая встретит то, что вы вписываете в инпут на HTML странице
$looking_for = filter_var(trim($_GET['input']), FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

function looking_in_articles(){
    global $pdo;
    global $looking_for;
    $sql_looking_for_firms = $pdo->query("SELECT * FROM `firms` WHERE `Main_title` LIKE '%$looking_for%' "); 
    return $sql_looking_for_firms;
}

// теперь результат кладем в переменную, я для удобства назвал ее так же как и функцию
$looking_in_articles = looking_in_articles()
```

Обратите внимание, что нужно использовать то соединение с БД, которое у вас реализовано, я например через PDO подключаюсь

Это довольно старенький пример, из моих первых больших проектов, но он рабочий.

Не нужно копировать код, разумеется, главное поймите суть.

Результат выведите в конце скрипта обработчика недофункцией echo, текст в результате работы обработчика появится в out вашего JS файла

Comment: Спасибо большое за подробное описание, сейчас пытаюсь понять и реализовать, напишу как получится. Ещё раз спасибо.

Comment: Если останутся доп вопросы, заходите в чат, обсудим что как https://t.me/notDevsChat

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

если вам нужно чтобы браузер, при клике по вашей ссылке попытался совершить вызов, попробуйте использовать протокол wtai

```html
<a href='wtai://*100#'>проверка баланса</a>
```

// в j2me точно работало

Comment: Здравствуйте, спасибо что откликнулись. У меня другой случай - через код JS, и запрос в БД выводится телефон на странице объявления. В таком случае можно добиться кликабельности номера телефона ?

Comment: сразу в html или догружать из бд с js без разницы, главное чтоб ссылка была корректная.и да, каюсь забыл про протокол tel: упомянутый в ответе выше. насколько помню у меня на nokia s40 j2me точно работал wtai но не работал tel. возможна и обратная ситуация когда браузер поддерживает tel но не поддерживает wtai. так что придется проверять useragent...

Comment: Спасибо большое, буду пробовать, позже напишу.

Answer (score 0):

И снова здравствуйте, не получается реализовать идею, как только перевожу ссылку в html сразу все перестаёт работать.
Как переделать всё ? здесь код - https://pastebin.com/q1Hk2uyA

Comment: Спасибо большое Всем, всё сделал, тема закрыта.